# What is the probability that 3 persons A, B and C have their birthday on same date of the year

Tags: probability

What is the probability that 3 persons A, B and C have their birthday on same date of the year.
given that their birthday is in a non-leap year?

Comment: $$\frac1{(365)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Without loss of generality, you can assume $A$ is born on April 20.  What is the probability that $B$ is also born on April 20?  What is the probability that $C$ is also born on April 20?